# ios method to insert spaces in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

In my app I download a file from amazon's s3, which does not work unless the file name has no spaces in it. For example, one of the files is "HoleByNature". I would like to display this to the user as "Hole By Nature", even though the file name will still have no spaces in it.

I was thinking of writing a method to search through the string starting at the 1st character (not the 0th) and every time I find a capital letter I create a new string with a substring until that index with a space and a substring until the rest.

So I have two questions.

1. If I use NSString's characterAtIndex, how do I know if that character is capital or not?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for all unicode uppercase and titlecase letters

```
- (NSString*) spaceUppercase:(NSString*) text {
    NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];
    for (int i = 0; i < [text length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [text characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([set characterIsMember:c] && i!=0){
            [result appendFormat:@" %C",c];
        } else {
            [result appendFormat:@"%C",c];
        }
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You know you could just use the standard C function `isupper`, right?

Comment: @Jano i edited your answer -- feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Comment: hmmm. this didn't work. I put this NSLog(@"space method try: %@",[self spaceUppercase:@"HoleByNature"]); and got this: 2012-08-26 21:18:56.391 <app name>[9492:707] space method try: HoleByNature

Comment: it seems as if the characterIsMember is never returning YES. so it isn't finding a match?

Comment: okay got it working using the isupper function. thanks Richard J. Ross III.

Comment: Surely the issue with `isupper` is that it knows only ASCII and is therefore going to have serious issues with a whole bunch of languages? The `NSCharacterSet` route will be fully compatible with all languages that have a notion of capitalised letters. Though I'd have been tempted to use a `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` and `substringWithRange:` approach to cut down on total work (admittedly at the cost of creating more objects).

Comment: I'm too late to edit my previous comment, but just to add: it's `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` you want, not `capitalizedLetterCharacterSet` (look up title case versus upper case); I edited the code. Other than starting at `i = 0` it's now working.

Comment: If you don't want a space at the beginning use: if ([set characterIsMember:c] && i!=0){

Answer (score 2):

I would not go to that approach because I know you can download files with spaces try this please when you construct the NSUrl object
@"my_web_site_url\sub_domain\sub_folder\My%20File.txt

this will download "My File.txt" from the URL provided. so basically you can replace all spaces in the URL with %20

reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: oh, I did notice that whenever I created URLs with paths that had spaces it would put the %20 wherever there was a space! I will definitely look into fixing this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with Jano's answer but using the isupper function as suggested by Richard J. Ross III.

```
- (NSString*) spaceUppercase:(NSString*) text 
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];
    [result appendFormat:@"%C",[text characterAtIndex:0]];
    for (int i = 1; i < [text length]; i++) 
    {
         unichar c = [text characterAtIndex:i];
         if (isupper(c))
         {  
             [result appendFormat:@" %C",c];
         } 
         else 
         {
             [result appendFormat:@"%C",c];
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```